# jqGrid jQuery Hexadecimal Colorpicker from dummy column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Spec : Trial based JqGrid 5.5 from "http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html" used .

I need a Dummy Column in ColModal as last column ( other columns have Ajaxed data from serverside)
The Dummy Column should have a Jquery Hexadecimal Colorpicker. [image]

Status: I have created a Dummy Column successfully, but was not able to implement a Jquery-Color-Picker

Requirement : **Multi-selected row Data from columns & Hexadecmal value from the Dummy Column**  need to be fetched.

Does nay body have brilliant ideas ?

Comment: Which colorpicker is supposed to be used?

Comment: I need a simple JQuery based Color picker , so that the Data from other columns could be Charted in the color selected from the specific row .. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided here uses a custom formatter and unformat function to get the selected value. For the demo we use [this colorpicker](https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker)

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    multiselect : true,
    colModel: [
        ...,
        // virual field  
        { label : "Color",
            name: "color_picker",
            width : 100,
            formatter : function() {
                // create a custom button for the color picker
                return "<button class='colorpick'>Color</button>";
            },
            // get the value from the button when using getRowData
            unformat : function( elem, op, cellval ) {
                return $("button",cellval).val();
            }
        },
        ...
    ],
    gridComplete : function() {
        // attach a colorpicker to the buttons
        $('.colorpick').colorpicker({
           inline: false,
           showNoneButton: true,
           showCloseButton: true,
           showCancelButton: true,
           colorFormat: ['#HEX'],
           modal: true
        });
    }, 
    ...
});
$("#mybuttondata").on("click", function(){
    // get the selected value from  colorpicker
    var get_selected  = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
    if(get_selected.length) {
        for(var i=0;i<get_selected.length;i++) {
            console.log( $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getRowData',get_selected[i]));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This sample works and Color Picker has limitations of not displaying the color selected in the column, rather the Hex value is dispalyed

thx Tony for the tip

Comment: @N.S.Karthik, glad to help. This was just a example on how to use it. The colorpicker has a lot of options, so we need to read all of them.

Comment: Tony thx for the Code snippet.. I used 2 types of Jquery Color pickers 
a) jquery-simple-color  b) colorpicker (as suggested by u ) Both worked